# Jquery script not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script to add a class to a div

```
jQuery('.responsive-calendar .today a').addClass('selectedDay');
```

This script works on the initial load of the page and adds the class. But on refreshing the page, this doesn't work and the class is not added.

So is there any function that I can use to load this script on the page refresh. I have tried adding this to the following function, but with no luck.

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {...});
jQuery(window).load(function(){...});
jQuery(window).on('load',function() { ... });
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: write it inside `document.ready`?

Comment: wrap your code like following:

$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });

moreover what do you mean bu initial load and page refresh? if page is refreshed then this is initial load for code as well.

Comment: It is written inside document.ready

Comment: You should include details of the calendar plugin in the question (it's in a comment in an answer, but should ideally be here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `jQuery(document).ready()`

Example:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.responsive-calendar .today a').addClass('selectedDay');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE:**
For your calendar, use its `onInit()` callback!

Example:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar({
            onInit: function() {
                $('.responsive-calendar .today a').addClass('selectedDay');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: *Why?* most likely, given the class names involved, it's because it's a 3rd-party component, possibly generated via javascript.  So *can't* be changed in the back-end.

Comment: If it is generated by javascript, then it means, that the block may not exists when document is ready. Consider to add a timeout before executing your function.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I am using the responsive-calendar plugin from w3widgets http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/. So i can't add the class in the backend.

Comment: There is an onInit() callback. I have updated the answer with an example!